# Purpose of condition inside a loop function that slice and reverse a list

Tags: python, list, data-structures, jupyter

## can Someone Please explain this code to me?

> I didn't get the part after the if-condition like why we used `if(i != 2):`?

```
sampleList = [11, 45, 8, 23, 14, 12, 78, 45, 89]
print("Original list ", sampleList)

length = len(sampleList)
chunkSize  = int(length/3)
start = 0
end = chunkSize
for i in range(1, 4, 1):
   indexes = slice(start, end, 1)
   listChunk = sampleList[indexes]
   print("Chunk ", i , listChunk)
   print("After reversing it ", list(reversed(listChunk)))
   start = end
   if(i != 2):
   end +=chunkSize
   else:
   end += length - chunkSize
```

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables in different moments or run in debuger or run on http://pythontutor.com/ to see step-by-step.

Comment: BTW: you can get the same result with `for start in range(0, length, chunkSize):    indexes = slice(start, start+chunkSize)` without `if`

Comment: you have even reduce to `for start in range(0, length, chunkSize): listChunk = sampleList[start:start+chunkSize]`

Answer (score 1):

`if i != 2:` is useful when original list has lenght `10` or `11` (or not divided by `3`) because last chunk need to get `4` or `5` elements instead of `3`

If you add element (ie. `1234`) to list you will have `10` elements

```
sampleList = [11, 45, 8, 23, 14, 12, 78, 45, 89, 1234]
```

and you get longer last chunk

```
Original list  [11, 45, 8, 23, 14, 12, 78, 45, 89, 1234]
Chunk  1 [11, 45, 8]
After reversing it  [8, 45, 11]
Chunk  2 [23, 14, 12]
After reversing it  [12, 14, 23]
Chunk  3 [78, 45, 89, 1234]
After reversing it  [1234, 89, 45, 78]
```

Using `end +=chunkSize` for last chunk you would get `3` elements in last chunk without `1234`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to replace `end += chunckSize` to the last four lines of code you will get the same result. This because when `i = 2` the `slice` function using `end` variable returns the same result when you use `end += length - chunckSize`. I personally suggest to keep only `end += chunckSize` because it is more readable.